# Eclipse - Debug As window

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I press F11 to debug my Android application I get 'Debug as' window in which I need to select 'Android application' in order to continue. Is it possible to suppress this window and always, by default go with 'Android application' option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse 3.5, the default launching operations has changed, and while the new behaviour is more powerful, sometimes it can be uncomfortable or annoying.

If you go to Window - Preferences - Run/Debug - Launching and in the 'Launch Operation' group select the first 'Always launch the previously launched application' option, F11 will always use the last run or debug configuration you use without further asking.